# Serialize multiple object of class but list value are the same

Tags: c#, list, object, xml-serialization

I would like to serialize this class by creating multiple objects. the method works and the objects are saved in the xml file but the values of the List  variable are always the same for all objects. how can i do to correct.?

```
 [Serializable()]
public class TextureValues

{
    [XmlAttribute("Texture_Info")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }

   
    public List<Point> Points { get; set; }
    public int Pensize { get; set; }
    public int Width { get; set; }
    public int Height { get; set; }

    public TextureValues() { }

    public TextureValues(string name, string date ,List<Point> points,int pensize,int width,int heigth)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Date = date;
        this.Points = points;
        this.Pensize = pensize;
        this.Width = width;
        this.Height = heigth;

    }
}
```

Below the method I used in the form to enter object parameters:

```
public partial class TextureMaker : Form
{
    List<TextureValues> textureInfo = new List<TextureValues>();
    List<Point> p = new List<Point>();
    
    public TextureMaker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void panelText_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        p.Add(panelText.PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
    }

    private void buttonSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       
        textureInfo.AddRange(new TextureValues[]
            {
                new TextureValues(textBoxName.Text,DateTime.Now.ToString(),p,(int)numericPenSize.Value,(int)numTextWidth.Value,(int)numTextHeight.Value)
            });

        var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\textures.xml";
        FileStream stream = File.Create(path); 
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<TextureValues>));
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(stream, textureInfo);
        stream.Close();
        p.Clear();
     }

}
```

Comment: " but the values of the List variable are always the same for all objects" you add only 1 element to your list in the code. I don't really understand you

Comment: what are you seeing, and what are you *expecting* to see? it isn't clear

Comment: every time I start the "buttonSave_Click" method the object is serialized inside the xml file, with the parameters I insert from the form including the coordinates of the points that I capture with the "panelText_Click" method. The problem is that inside the xml file the saved points are the same for all objects while I would like to have different values,